# segmentation fault for string function argument

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a simple main code that gives me segmentation fault when calling a function. In the following code, I have two functions, the first one works correctly but the program doesn't enter the second one and gives me segmentation fault error. Is there any reason for that? I have made sure about the following:

1. The variables `o` and `c` are not out of bound.
2. `cn` is initialized correctly.
3. I have a read-only access to `cm` and `argv`. Plus it does not even enter the function `evaluate`

Here is the code:

```
void print_cm(vector<vector<int> > *cm, char* gtf);                                                                                                        
void evaluate(vector<vector<int> > *cm, char* gtf);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int o = 2; // It is initialized
    int c = 4; // It is initialized
    vector<vector<int> > cm; // It is initialized
    if (argc>4)
        print_cm(&cm, argv[o]);
    if (argc>4)
    {
        cout << argv[c] << endl; // Works
        // The following also works
        for (int i=0; i<cm.size(); i++)
            for (int j=0; j<cm[i].size(); j++)
                 cout << cm[i][j] << " ";
        // The following causes segmentation fault;
        evaluate(&cm, argv[c]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void evaluate(vector<vector<int> > *cm, char* gtf)
{
    // Read-only access to cm and gtf
}

void print_cm(vector<vector<int> > *cm, char* gtf)
{
    // Read-only access to cm and gtf
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include "includes/Utility.h"
#include "includes/Graph.h"


void print_cm(vector<vector<int> > *cores, char* output);
void evaluate(vector<vector<int> > const *cm, char* gtf);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int g = -1, c = -1, o = -1;
    for (int i=1; i<argc-1; i++) 
        if (argv[i][0]=='-')
        {
            if (argv[i][1]=='g')
                g = i + 1;
            else if (argv[i][1]=='c')
                c = i + 1;
            else if (argv[i][1]=='k')
                ki = i + 1;
            else if (argv[i][1]=='s')
                si = i + 1;
            else if (argv[i][1]=='o')
                o = i + 1;
        }
    Graph G;
    if (c>0) G.read_input(argv[g], argv[c]);
    else G.read_input(argv[g]);
    if (ki > 0) 
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[ki]);
        cout << k << endl;
    }
    if (si > 0) 
    {
        int s = atoi(argv[si]);
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    // Find communities
    vector<vector<int> > cores;
    G.partitioning(&cores);
    if (o>0) 
        print_cm(&cores, argv[o]);
        if (c>0) 
        {
            cout << "here" << endl;
            for (size_t i=0; i<cores.size(); i++)
                for (size_t j=0; j<cores[i].size(); j++)
                    if (cores.at(i).at(j)<0) cout << "here";
            cout << "here" << endl;
            evaluate(&cores, argv[c]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void print_cm(vector<vector<int> > *cores, char* output)
{

    ofstream out;
    out.open(output);
    for(size_t i=0; i<(*cores).size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j<(*cores)[i].size(); j++)
            out << (*cores)[i][j] << " ";
        out << endl;
    }
    out.close();

    return ;
}

void evaluate(vector<vector<int> > const *cm, char* gtf)
{
    // we evaluate precision, recall, F1 and F2
    vector<vector<int> > gt;
    ifstream in;
    char str[100000000];
    in.open(gtf);
    while(in.getline(str, 100000000))
    {
        stringstream s;
        s << str;
        int a;
        gt.resize(gt.size()+1);
        while (s >> a) gt[gt.size()-1].push_back(a);
    }
    in.close();

    cout << "==================== Evaluation  Results ====================" << endl;
    int imax = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<(*cm).size(); i++)
        imax = max(imax, *max_element((*cm)[i].begin(), (*cm)[i].end()));

    for(size_t i=0; i<gt.size(); i++)
        imax = max(imax, *max_element(gt[i].begin(), gt[i].end()));

    vector<bool> flag(imax, false);
    vector<double> recall((*cm).size(), 0), precision((*cm).size(), 0), f1((*cm).size(), 0), f2((*cm).size(), 0);
    int overlap;
    double size = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<(*cm).size(); i++)
    {
        // evaluate
        size += (double) (*cm)[i].size();
        for(size_t j=0; j<(*cm)[i].size(); j++)
            flag[(*cm)[i][j]] = true;

        double p, r, ff1, ff2;
        for(size_t j=0; j<gt.size(); j++)
        {
            overlap = 0;
            for(size_t k=0; k<gt[j].size(); k++)
                if (flag[gt[j][k]]) overlap++;

            p = (double) overlap / (double) (*cm)[i].size();
            if (p > precision[i])
                precision[i] = p;

            r = (double) overlap / (double) gt[j].size();
            if (r > recall[i])
                recall[i] = r;

            ff1 = (double) 2*(p*r)/(p+r);
            if (ff1 > f1[i])
                f1[i] = ff1;

            ff2 = (double) 5*(p*r)/(4*p + r);
            if (ff2 > f2[i])
                f2[i] = ff2;
        }

        for(size_t j=0; j<(*cm)[i].size(); j++)
            flag[(*cm)[i][j]] = false;
    }

    double Recall = 0, Precision = 0, F1 = 0, F2 = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<(*cm).size(); i++)
    {
        Recall += recall[i];
        Precision += precision[i];
        F1 += f1[i];
        F2 += f2[i];
    }
    cout << "+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+" << endl;
    cout << "|  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << "Precision";
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << "Recall";
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << "F1-measure";
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << "F2-measure";
    cout << "  |" << endl;
    cout << "|  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << Precision/(*cm).size() ;
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << Recall/(*cm).size();
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << F1/(*cm).size();
    cout << "  |  " << setiosflags( ios::left ) << setw(10) << F2/(*cm).size();
    cout << "  |" << endl;
    cout << "+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+" << endl;
    cout << "Number of communities: " << (*cm).size() << endl;
    cout << "Average community size: " << size/(*cm).size() << endl;

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out your mistakes. Debugger should be your friend and guide in a situation like this.

Comment: So we're just supposed to take it on your word that `// Read-only access to cm and gtf` doesn't do anything silly or that you are passing the correct number of args to the program?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If there's read only access in those functions.... then why aren't you using pointers to const vectors?

Comment: @user657267 first of all, the first function works fine. Secondly, I could print the result in before the function call in the `if` statement

Comment: @ernab the point is your issue is in the code you aren't showing, post an mvce.

Comment: Also: How many parameters are you passing to the executable? There's no check against argc.

Comment: @emab That the first function is working fine has nothing to say. The second could still contain code equivalent to cm = nullptr; cm->size();

Comment: @ernab a valgrind dump != an mvce, for what it's worth at least it confirms that the issue is in the code you aren't showing, you're probably doing something daft like casting a vector.

Comment: @user657267 @Daniel It doesn't even enter the function `evaluate`. Let alone to doing something inside it.

Comment: Almost always the problem is in the code not posted. You don't understand the reason for the bug, don't assume that you understand the rest of your code either. Post a **minmal** **complete** program.

Comment: @ernab actually this looks like an out of bound access on `cm` or another vector, replace all of the `[]` operators with `std::vector::at` to confirm.

Comment: @emab How can you tell that it doesn't enter the function? Can you please just show the code, or at least confirm that the issue is still there when changing to VECT const * const where VECT is your vector type.

Comment: @user657267 I replaced `[i]` with `.at(i)` and and it still prints all the content of the vector. But it doesn't enter the function.

Comment: @DanielJour Of course I uploaded the complete code

Comment: @john I meant to simplify the problem. I have put the complete code.

Comment: @ernab that is about as far from a **minimal**, verified, complete example as you can get, but in any case you haven't posted the includes and you haven't given any sample input. What's `Graph` for instance? What should `argv` hold?

Comment: @DanielJour I tried `const` for the vector pointer in the function argument and I am still getting the same error, please look at the modified answer.

Comment: I got the answer, should I delete the question for all the downvotes now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char str[100000000];
```

This is in your `evaluate` function. This are 100 million bytes, or about 95 MB that you're allocating on the stack.

Typical stack sizes are far less than that, around 1 MB.

So apart from possible other problems this is most likely causing a stack overflow.

When entering the function, the stack frame gets extended to be large enough to hold the local variables. As soon as the stack is used then (to write a default value) you're accessing invalid (non stack, thankfully protected) memory.

Comment: That's right, it was the cause of it. Why it doesn't enter the function though?

Comment: The error is most likely during building the stack frame for the function, I.e. exactly when entering the function.